# Keep selected toggle/tab open on a page that keeps being reloaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, toggle

I would like to keep a selected toggle open on a page that keeps getting reloaded.

the INFO.php page has the toggle on:

```
<div class="toggle toggle-transparent toggle-bordered-simple">
<div class="toggle">
    <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</label>
    <div class="toggle-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the page that keeps loading it:

```
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <div id="portfolio" class="portfolio-gutter mt-20 mb-60">
                    <div class="row mix-grid refreshed">
                        <?php include 'INFO.php'; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

and for the reload:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(
                function ()
                {
                    $('.refreshed').load('INFO.php').fadeIn();
                }, 10000);

    </script>
```

Comment: Can you make working fiddle?

Comment: I don't think jsfiddle supports php?

Comment: Yes, but you just omit php part as it would be fetching some content.

Comment: Why are you constantly reloading the content every 10 seconds? We need a little bit more context as to what functionality you're trying to implement and why you want it.

Comment: The INFO.php page will be filled with differenttabs containing SQLdata. the tabs/toggle will have the data divided in for example different cities: Amsterdam has its own tab and London.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example hot to achieve it, storing the value of an open tab in a variable. Alternatively, you can store it in a cookie, if you want it to persist next time user visits the page.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var simulatedContent = $($("#wrapper").html());

  var open_tab = 1
  
  
  function initTabs(){
    $(".tab"+open_tab).show()
    $(".tabs li a").on("click",function(){
       var i = $(this).data("tab");
       open_tab = i
       $(".tab").hide()
       $(".tabs li").removeClass('active');
       $(this).parent().addClass('active');
       $(".tab"+i).show()
        
    })
  }
  
  var auto_refresh = setInterval(function ()
  {
      $('#wrapper').html("<h3>loading..</h3>")
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#wrapper').html(simulatedContent);
        initTabs()
      }, 500);
  }, 3000);
  
  initTabs()
})
```

```css
* { font-family:Arial}
.tab { padding:5px;display:none;height:100px;background:#efefef;}
.tabs li {  background:grey;padding: 5px;width:33% }
.tabs li.active { background:black;}
.tabs li a { color:white;display:block;text-decoration:none;}
.tabs { height: 30px;margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;display:flex;width: 100%; background: grey;  clear:both;}
#wrapper { background: grey; width: 300px; height: 130px;}
h3 { text-align:center; margin:0;padding-top: 50px; font-size: 15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
<ul class="tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="javascript:;" data-tab="1">tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:;" data-tab="2">tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:;" data-tab="3">tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab tab1">tab 1 content</div>
<div class="tab tab2">tab 2 content</div>
<div class="tab tab3">tab 3 content</div>
</div>
```